# Problem Installing Domino App Dev Pack into Node

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

I am attempting to install the `domino-db` module into `node`:

`npm install ./packages/domino-domino-db-1.1.0.tgz --save`

Install fails when trying to install `grpc 1.14.1` which occurs once a number of other packages have been installed, error message as below.

1209 verbose pkgid grpc@1.14.1

1210 verbose cwd /node_projects/project1

1211 verbose Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64

1212 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install" "./packages/domino-domino-db-1.1.0.tgz" "--save"

1213 verbose node v11.6.0

1214 verbose npm  v6.5.0-next.0

1215 error code ELIFECYCLE

1216 error errno 1

1217 error grpc@1.14.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
1217 error Exit status 1

1218 error Failed at the grpc@1.14.1 install script.

1218 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

1219 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

NodeJS version is 11.6.0

Does anyone have any idea of the root cause and workaround?

Comment: The problem is caused by using Node 11.6.0. Install works fine on Node 10.15.0

Answer (score 3):

The current version of domino-db was tested and released with Node 8 support (LTS at the time). The next release of domino-db is being tested and released with Node 10 (LTS now) support.

We are aiming to always support the latest LTS releases.